# Why substitute doesn't work in silent mode?

Tags: substitute, ex-mode, silent-mode

I'm playing with `ex` and I've found that removing trailing spaces for multiple files in silent mode doesn't work as expected.

The following examples doesn't work as expected (whatever I use `argdo` or `bufdo`):

```
$ ex -s +'argdo! %s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.*
$ ex -s +'bufdo! %s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.*
(nothing is changed)
```

My files have trailing spaces as I've tested in git repository, so I could easily check the changes via `git diff`. And in addition exactly the same command (without `-s`) works as expected:

```
$ ex +'bufdo! %s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.*
7 files to edit
```

What's more unexpected, silent mode works for other example such as:

```
$ ex -s +'bufdo! %s/foo/bar/e' -cxa *.*
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Debugging with `-V10` doesn't give me much useful information I guess.

Comment: Sounds to me like its a bug.

Comment: `vi -es +'bufdo! %s/\s\+$//e' -cxa ...` works here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is, that the `bufdo` and `argdo` command iterate over all buffers themselves. However without writing your changes, vim will refuse to load the next buffer, **unless** the ['hidden'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'hidden') option is set (which it is not by default) or the argument to the `buf/arg-doc` comment does write the change itself.

So this will work:

```
ex -s -c'bufdo! %s/\s\+$//e|w' -cx *
```

or alternatively using `:set hidden`:

```
ex --cmd ':set hidden' -s -c'bufdo! %s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *
```

Comment: And of course this is a non-issue if you put `:set hidden` in your startup files. (Are there people that really prefer `nohidden`?)

Comment: mostly people who are not bothering to customize vim (and don't have a .vimrc). BTW: it `ex` in silent mode does not read .vimrc file

Comment: Ah, good to know. Based on `:h .vimrc`, the `plugin` files do get loaded by `ex`? I have `set hidden` in one of those, so I imagine it isn't a problem for me

Comment: More interestingly, I get an exit code of 1 when I use ex like this.

Comment: Isn't what exclamation mark after `bufdo` should force to load the next buffer (as per `bufdo!`)?

Comment: @kenorb well, apparently not (or perhaps it does load the new buffer, but discards the changes) in silent mode.